# USB MFP print server that works with Windows x64?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, home-networking, print-server, multi-function-printer

Right now, we are using the Longshine LCS-MFP101-2 to connect to our MFP device (printer/scanner combo) over LAN. However, the required driver (RMVUSB, Remote Virtual USB) cannot be installed on 64 bit Windows operating systems such as Windows XP x64 or Windows 7 x64. Since the distributor lists the product as "phased out", I do not expect any updated 64 bit drivers any time soon. :/

Because of that, I am searching for a relatively cheap SOHO MFP print server (1 USB port should be enough) which can be used with 32 bit and 64 bit versions of Windows. Do you have any ideas or recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Any modern multifunction printer will work on both 32-bit or 64-bit Windows. Which one is best for you depends on your exact needs.

You can start by asking the [query on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_sc_0_21?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=multifunction+printer&sprefix=multifunction+printer#/ref=sr_st?keywords=multifunction+printer&qid=1294500980&rh=n%3A172282%2Ck%3Amultifunction+printer&sort=price) in descending order of price, and pick out products by any of the well-known printer manufacturers. More information is available in product details or on the manufacturer's site. Amazon Rating is also very interesting, as are user reviews.

Just beware that a cheap printer might be quite costly on ink, so that in fact a printer's price means nothing. It's better to verify the number-of-pages per cartridges and their price. Generic cartridges are cheaper, but may cause harm to the printer.

Consumer websites are an important source of information, for example [this comparison](http://www.consumersearch.com/multifunction-printer-reviews/compare).

Comment: The printer is not really the subject in question in this case. Yes, a modern multifunction printer will most likely work on Win x86 and x64, but I am (still) in need of a USB print server for an existing printer. I just put out the bounty now, because I hoped the market might have changed after a year. :)

Comment: All those MFP print servers do - AFAIK - is to provide a virtual USB port over ethernet, so that a connected computer can use the device as if it was connected to a local port. The idea is to provide all the functionality, which can be pretty tricky with a normal print server. (A bit OT, but I object having a old PC running all the time (at least for now), because of the power consumption.)

Comment: This minimal functionality can be done even by a hub with USB.

Comment: Thanks for that idea, but most of the ethernet hubs that I found just provided a print server which will be fine in most cases, but does not allow scanning over LAN, AFAIK. Did you have any specific manufacturer/model in mind?

Comment: I am no specialist, but querying Amazon's Electronics section for "hub usb print server scan" got me several candidates, some of which look nice.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is more than a year old but it's still hard to find info on this subject even in 2011. Yes, there are MFP servers that are 64-bit compatible but they have been fairly hard to find. After several weeks of research, as of March 2011, there are several, including Hawking HMPS1U and Linksys WPSM54G multifunction print servers that will work. I'm not sure about when the Hawking came out, but the Linksys one began supporting 64-bit Windows OS starting the same month you posted your question (12/09). However, it required both the firmware (v. 1019) and windows setup wizard software to be upgraded in order to be 64-bit compatible.

Answer (score 0):

As @harrymc mentioned, any new printer will work with both x86 and x64 Windows. What I can add is that external USB printservers are unreliable at best (printer manufacturers also don't help the situation). So it's best to pay $30-$40 more and have printer with integrated printserver supported by the manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but as I already mentioned, the printer is not really subject to change here. :) If there is (still) no USB print server that delivers print and scan over LAN on Win x86 and x86-x64, then so be it. ^^